# How to prove the inequality: $\frac{(1+x)^2}{2x^2+(1-x)^2}+\frac{(1+y)^2}{2y^2+(1-y)^2}+\frac{(1+z)^2}{2z^2+(1-z)^2}\leq 8$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that:

$$\frac{(1+x)^2}{2x^2+(1-x)^2}+\frac{(1+y)^2}{2y^2+(1-y)^2}+\frac{(1+z)^2}{2z^2+(1-z)^2}\leq 8$$

subject to the constraints:

$$x,y,z >0$$

and

$$x+y+z=1.$$

Comment: You have typos if the two first equations : the last "y" must be replaced by "z".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if $a+b+c=1,a,b,c>0$
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2+2a+1}{3a^2-2a+1}\le 8$$
since
$$\dfrac{a^2+2a+1}{3a^2-2a+1}\le 4a+\dfrac{4}{3}$$
this is true becasuse
$$\Longleftrightarrow 3(4a+1)(a-\dfrac{1}{3})^2\ge 0$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{(a+1)^2}{2a^2+(1-a)^2}\le 4(a+b+c)+4=8$$

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, where did the motivation for looking at: $(4a+1)(a-1/3)^2$ come from?

Comment: it must have $(a-1/3)$

Answer (score 3):

An other proof:
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{cyc}\dfrac{(2a+b+c)^2}{2a^2+(b+c)^2}\le 8$$
since
$$\dfrac{(2a+b+c)^2}{2a^2+(b+c)^2}\le\dfrac{4}{3}\dfrac{4a+b+c}{a+b+c}$$
this is true because
$$\Longleftrightarrow (2a-b-c)^2(5a+b+c)\ge 0$$
so
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{(2a+b+c)^2}{2a^2+(b+c)^2}\le\dfrac{4}{3}\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{4a+b+c}{a+b+c}=8$$